# What Exactly is a ViewModel?

Tags: angularjs, mvvm

I'm pretty decent with Angular, I understand it's MVVM design pattern.

From a very basic level, I have come to know the following:

-view: the visual output a user can see of the application

-model: the data that populates the application

-viewmodel: ???

I have seen it used the following naming convention for a custom directive:

```
controller: myController,
        controllerAs: 'vm'
```

I'm also aware the controller really connects the view and the model. But beyond that level of understanding, Im having trouble understanding exactly its significance.

Answer (score 0):

The

In that code it´s using ui-route controllerAs to set ´vm´ as the controller, so it doesn´t need to use the $scope, is kind of the same as:

```
var vm = this;
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not strictly related to AngularJS, but takes a more general approach to explain what a ViewModel is.

Sometimes attaching a model directly to a view is not what you want.
Consider an example where you have a person with FirstName and LastName, this will be your "model".

If you - in your view - want to display a persons fullname it could make sense to have a ViewModel called person that has a single property called Name. This ViewModel will be populated by concatenating FirstName and LastName with space in between.

This is just one example, another example could be that your ViewModel is represented by combining data from two or more different models, such as a person and address.